# "ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty" but SECRET_KEY is set

Tags: python, django

I'm working with Django 1.11 and Apache 2.2. My SECRET_KEY suddenly stopped working, I'm getting an error "ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty." even though the SECRET_KEY is definitely set in my settings.py --

**settings.py**

```
SECRET_KEY = 'yaddayaddayadda'
```

I know that there are lot of similar questions and I've read many of the answers and I still don't understand what's going wrong here. It was working and to me it seemed like it suddenly stopped working. Deleting the *.pyc files did not help.

**manage.py**

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
```

**wsgi.py**

```
path_1 = '/home/path/proj_website/mysite'
sys.path.append(path_1)

path_2 = '/home/path/proj_website/mysite/mysite'
sys.path.append(path_2)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
```

**Update**

I think my real problem is that my production server is not registering any changes to my settings.py file. I always do "touch wsgi.py" when I make a change and I cleared out my *pyc files and it's still not working. Like I said in a comment below, when I do "python manage.py runserver" it runs without error. So I don't think it's a path issue or an issue with project files but something with the web server. Any other suggestions of what I can try?

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure the paths and the `mysite` name are actually correct for your system? Has the project been moved since it last worked? Are there any other warnings that might hint at other configuration issues?

Comment: That's what's so weird, the site was working and I didn't move anything in directory tree when it stopped working. I had a warning about an unapplied migration and I deleted the migration.

Comment: You're almost certainly missing something, then; computers are fairly consistent in their behavior (well, aside from anything running Javascript), so I'd say step 1 is to figure out what changed. Perhaps check your unstaged changes or recent commits, and see if stashing or rolling back helps (hopefully you're using version control religiously).

Comment: One clue is that when I run "python manage.py runserver" I don't get any errors, which certainly wouldn't happen if my SECRET_KEY was actually empty. So I think my development server stopped picking up on mysite.settings for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

secret key should be a string not a list

```
SECRET_KEY = 'yaddayaddayadda'
```

Comment: I made that change and it didn't make any difference, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I think you shoould use a debugger and see what is exactly in `from django.conf import settings; settings.SECRET_KEY`

Comment: I did that and when I tried to print "settings.SECRET_KEY" I got this error message, "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting SECRET_KEY, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings." But I am setting the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable in both manage.py and wsgi.py...

Comment: don't use print, use a debugger (`pycharm` debugger or `pudb` are good)

Answer (score 0):

The resolution to what I put in the update is that I needed to restart the Apache server.